# How does one debug a module that is run as a script (with -m flag) from within PyDev?

Tags: pydev

I have a module that is part of a library I am writing. The library has multiple executables. These are run from the command line as a script with the syntax `python3 -m mypackage.mysubpackage.MyModule`

I am familiar with eclipse, its debugger and PyDev, but I have not found how to set a debug/run configuration to launch MyModule within PyDev.

I have tried to add `-m` or `-m mypackage.mysubpackage.MyModule` as VM arguments to python.exe within the Arguments section of the Debug Configuration, but this does not work even setting the appropriate working directory to have mypackage in the PYTHONPATH.

I know how to launch the program outside eclipse and connect it to eclipse using a debug server. I know I can also make a little auxiliary script that is not part of the library just to launch the program so I can run it inside eclipse, but I would prefer the convenience of being able to launch the module directly within eclipse itself and I feel PyDev should be able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just press `F9` PyDev should launch your module.

Although note it'll launch the file directly. If you require it to be launched with the `-m` flag (so that your relative imports resolve in that file), you can configure it in the preference:

`preferences > PyDev > Run > Launch modules with python -m ...`

PyDev will compute the module name based on the file location and PYTHONPATH configured in this case.

p.s.: You may want to take a look at http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_run.html for more details on re-launching your module, unit-tests, etc.

Comment: Thank you. The setting that you point out in the preferences does exactly what I wanted. Thank you also for pointing to the manual.

Comment: Great... as a note, if this worked for you, you should accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you, very useful - was looking for this one for some time.